# ERROR: schema "b" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

```
select a.gross, a.nett, a.cost,
    b.to_char(float8 (SUM(pymt+budget)*1000000)/(SUM(area)*40000),'FM999999999.00') AS xyz
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id=b.id 
AND id='123456';
```

Why am I keep getting this error msg:

```
ERROR:  schema "b" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: schema "b" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
```

Comment: You have an aliased function.

Answer (score 1):

Since `to_char` does not exist in your table `b` it tries to find it in an schema `b`:

```
b.to_char
```

Just delete the `b` and use it to qualify the column names:

```
to_char(
    float8 
        (SUM(b.pymt + a.budget) * 1000000) / 
        (SUM(b.area) * 40000)
    ,'FM999999999.00'
) AS xyz
```